# How can I skip Fabric connections that ask for a password?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I'm iterating over a few hundred EC2 instances but only have access to about 80% of them. I would like to skip any instances that have declined my SSH key and asked for a password.

Answer (score 2):

If the host is unreachable, then you can use `--skip-bad-hosts` option, otherwise 
Looks like you can use the settings context manager and try the ssh within that context manager and if the failure happens it can skip to the next one.  The docs for [context_manager.settings](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.0/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) have an example.

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    ssh_attempt # can fail
ssh_attemp # cannot fail
```

Comment: Will warn_only consider being asked for an SSH password failure?

Comment: Not sure try it, but try the fab with a timeout option too.