# Python Fabric: Skip logins needing passwords

Tags: python, ssh, passwords, fabric

I have a similar issue to this:
[How can I skip Fabric connections that ask for a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938324/how-can-i-skip-fabric-connections-that-ask-for-a-password)
which has no answer. I'm looking for a way to get Fabric to consider bad any host asking for a password instead of an SSH key login, since this means the user I'm connecting as doesn't have an account on the server (and I'm iterating through a large list of hosts). I've tried setting

```
env.password = None
```

and

```
env.password = 'none'
```

as well as

```
with setting(warn_only=True):
```

but Fabric keeps asking for the password. Any way around this?

Comment: `None or 'none'` will always evaluate as `'none'`.

Comment: @mizipzor Sorry, that wasn't literal Python code, I meant I've tried 'env.password = None' and 'env.password = 'none''

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe [env.abort_on_prompts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/usage/env.html#abort-on-prompts) will achieve what you need, i.e. fail if there is a need for any kind of user interaction, while working when public key authentication is possible.

According to the documentation, this option calls [abort()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.3/api/core/utils.html#fabric.utils.abort) which in turn make use of [sys.exit](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which raises [SystemExit](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit) making it possible to detect and recover from inner calls to `abort` by using `except SystemExit` or similar.

Comment: I found that option but unfortunately it does exactly what it says, kills the script at any prompts, even with warn_only, and I need it to ignore prompts. Thanks though!

Comment: I've revised the answer. According to the documentation, you should be able to recover from the `abort()` call simply by catching the `SystemExit` exception, therefore being able to continue the script execution and having your desired behaviour of ignoring hosts that require a password.

Comment: This sounds very promising, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Confirmed working, perfect. Only wish Fabric had the option to just skip these hosts from the outset!

Comment: Good to know. It's a possible interesting contribution for the project in the future.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my evening from hacking away on this!

Answer (score 0):

I just patched up the utils.py in fabric to return a raise instead of sys.exit(1). let's you handle it cleanly instead of it crapping itself.

```
(about line 34)
    else:
        #sys.exit(1)
        raise("I broke")
```