# Fabric: prevent asking for password

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

We have a few dozens for Amazon EC2 spot instances running simultaneously. We have to iterate over all of these instances and execute some command. But sometimes logging in fails for unknown reasons (maybe network issues or whatever). So on some instance fabric keeps asking for password, but I don't want it to do so.

The code:

```
env.hosts = [ip]
env.reject_interactive_password = True

env.hosts = ['%s@%s' % ('ubuntu', 'PASSWORD')]
env.host_string = '%s@%s' % ('ubuntu', ip)
env.user = 'ubuntu'
env.password = 'PASSWORD'

env.reject_unknown_hosts = False
env.disable_known_hosts = True

env.warn_only = True

run('some command')
```

As you can see, I have added reject_interactive_password but it does not work, unfortunately. So as you understand, our loop hangs on some instance and we don't reach the others (which is an issue).

We don't use ssh certificates for some reasons, only password-based auth.

We use the latest fabric from PIP.

So how to prevent fabric from asking a password at all? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Fabric: Skip logins needing passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569225/python-fabric-skip-logins-needing-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that fabric is prompting for the password and not something like `sudo` on the other end?  Take a look at the [fabric troubleshooting page](http://www.fabfile.org/troubleshooting.html) for some ideas on how to figure out *who* is prompting.

Take a look at using [env.passwords](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#passwords) since you can specify the password per host string.  You shouldn't have to do this, but it is good to know that you can.  You might want to experiment with the [env.use_shell](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/usage/env.html#use-shell) option as well if your commands do not take advantage of shell syntax.  I experimented with a number of these options to overcome some similar interactive password prompting.  Ultimately, we went to using SSH key-based access since it is simply cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: yes, it's not a command asking for sudo password since the ubuntu user is in the sudoers group at EC2, and it never asked me for sudo password when I executed some commands there manually

Answer (score 0):

I have found 'abort on prompt' option. It executes sys.exit() on any input prompt. That's not exactly what I need, and I've seen some people wanted it to skip this kind of things as well, not terminating. But ok, I can catch the exit signal and skip the current host. It's not a great thing and might have side effects but might be accepted as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want your script to continue after it gets an exception. You can probably tweak you connection timeout and wrap your code in a `try: ... except:` clause.   You can catch the exception that you get when you get a timeout and simply display a message and not exit.