# Python Fabric : abort_on_prompts doesn't work

Tags: python, fabric, ssh-keys

I'm trying to skip prompt during a SSH connection with Fabric. Like [Python Fabric: Skip logins needing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569225/python-fabric-skip-logins-needing-passwords) . I read in the documention that the option abort_on_prompts should do that. But I can't make it work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from fabric.api import *

env.abort_on_prompts=True

def remote_cmd(server_name):
  with settings(hide('output','running','warnings'),
                host_string=server_name,
                user = 'john',
                key_filename = '/home/john/id_rsa',
                warn_only=True):
  return run('ls /data/')


server_name = 'server01'
ls_result = remote_cmd(server_name)
```

This code keeps asking me for the server01's password (because it doesn't have the public key) whereas I want to skip it.

Comment: Are you sure that your `/home/john/id_rsa.pub` is in the remote `.ssh/authorized_keys` ?

Comment: No it is not in the remote; and I don't want it to be, that's why I want to skip it :)

Comment: Then how do you think the server can authenticate you ? How to be sure you are `john` without giving a password or a public key ? What do you expect ? The program to stop / to skip the connection ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I expect because "abort_on_prompts" is supposed to do that -> [Fabric documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/env.html#abort-on-prompts)

Comment: I do not have this issue while running your code : `Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: xxx), but abort-on-prompts was set to True. Aborting`

Comment: Interesting... I'm running Python 2.6.6 and Fabric 0.9 on Debian 6. I don't have this message it keeps asking me for the password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FunkySayu, I finally found the solution and what was wrong.
I used Python 2.6.6 and Fabric 0.9 on Debian 6.
So I tried it on a Debian 8 with Python 2.7.9 and Fabric 1.10 and it worked fine!

**abort_on_prompts** exits the script but I wanted to just skip it. Here is the solution I found :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from fabric.api import *

env.abort_on_prompts=True

def remote_cmd(server_name):
  with settings(hide('output','running','warnings'),
            host_string=server_name,
            user = 'john',
            key_filename = '/home/john/id_rsa',
            warn_only=True):
    return run('ls /data/')


servers = (('server01',), ('server02',))
for row in servers:
  server_name = row[0]

  print "Connection to ", server_name

  try:
    result_ls = remote_cmd(server_name)
    print result_ls
  except SystemExit:
    print server_name," doesn't have the key"
```

In this example **server01** doesn't have public key in authorized_key file. But no harm, the script will continue, print a message, and then run the command on **server02**.
I hope it's clear :)

```
me@myserver:~$ ./test_fabric.py
Connection to  server01

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: server01), but abort-on-prompts was set to True

Aborting.
server01  doesn't have the key

Connection to server02
[we see the results of ls command]
```

Comment: Also work on Debian 7 with Python 2.7.3 and Fabric 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the python fabric.api **env.abort_on_prompts = True** and manage the abort event, it's a must to use it together with a **try/except SystemExit** statement. Below it's a simple example, ***abort_on_promt_test.py***, to test it in your localhost defining a local role for the execution.

```
from fabric.api import settings, env, run
from termcolor import colored

env.roledefs = {
    'local': ['localhost'],
}


def command(cmd):
    """
Run a command in the host/s
    :param cmd: bash command to be executed
     eg: fab -R local command:"hostname"
     eg: fab -R local command:"ls -ltra"
    """

    env.abort_on_prompts = True
    try:
        with settings(warn_only=False):
            run(cmd)
    except SystemExit:
        print colored('===============================================', 'red')
        print colored('HOST: ' + env.host_string + ' aborted on prompt', 'red')
        print colored('===============================================', 'red')
```

Here's the **output** of its **test execution**:

```
delivery@delivery-E5450$ fab -f abort_on_promt_test.py -R local command:"hostname"
[localhost] Executing task 'command'
[localhost] run: hostname

Fatal error: Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: localhost), but abort-on-prompts was set to True

Aborting.
===============================================
HOST: localhost aborted on prompt
===============================================

Done.
```